CUDA: Does the SM thread count matter when sizing a kernel's block
There are countless articles and SO questions explaining what a kernel's grid and block sizes should be set to and how to optimise these values, but the articles never seem to mention the SM limits. My understanding is that an SM can execute a maximum of 1536 threads and a maximum of 8 blocks. Surely these values have some relevance in such calculations, so why don't they crop up more?
E.g. if my kernel's block size is 128 threads then each SM will only run 1024 out of a possible 1536 threads, which is quite the under-utilisation.
Or maybe it's just me, and it's taken this long for that particular light-bulb moment, while everyone else "just knows" to factor in these things!

These values are architecture dependent. Server accelerators have had 2048 threads per SM for the recent generations, i.e. the values are not even the same for all Ampere cards. See this table.

Different GPU architectures have different SM thread limits.  1536 is common, but 1024 and 2048 exist also, depending on arch.    SMs are generally not limited to 8 blocks, not sure where you got that. There is a table in the programming guide that covers these limits, not to mention numerous online posts.  A block size of 128 should not cause problems (by itself) and can easily fill an SM on a GPU whether it has a limit of 1024, 1536, or 2048.  The issue I sometimes point out is 1024 threads per block will under-utilize an SM with a limit of 1536.

"[W]hy don't they crop up more?" seems like a weirdly meta question for SO. I agree that a good answer concerning block size should mention these limits. I personally cite them when coming across people trying to use very few threads per block. One reason might be that even before arriving at these limits with less than 2-3 warps per block one often starts getting poor performance due to inefficient memory access given the size of memory pages (1024 B). Therefore given a memory-bound kernel with linear access pattern and 4 B (8 B) accesses, one wants at least 256 (128) threads per block.

BTW This argument comes from Nvidia's Stephen Jones (CUDA Architect) in his GTC 2022 talk How CUDA Programming Works, so I trust the information, but I have asked myself before why one can't find this information in the "CUDA Best Practices Guide" instead of just "Between 128 and 256 threads per block is a good initial range for experimentation with different block sizes."...

tl;dr:  These numbers don't appear more often because:

You're looking at the wrong numbers.
The numbers you're looking at are very microarchitecture-dependent.


Now for the longer version:

My understanding is that an SM can execute a maximum of 1536 threads and a maximum of 8 blocks.

Assuming you mean NVIDIA GPUs with compute capabilities 8.6-8.9, and looking at the CUDA compute capabilities table, we find:



Feature
CC 8.6/8.7
CC 8.9




Maximum number of resident blocks per SM
16
24


Maximum number of resident threads per SM
1536
1536



and I assume this is where you got the number 1536. (Still, not 8 blocks per SM, but 16 or 24).
Yet if we look at compute capability 8.0, e.g. on the A40 cards, it is 2048 resident threads, not 1536; and 32 resident blocks. Ditto for compute capability 9.0. So, like @RobertCrovella wrote in this comment, this is very architecture-dependent.
but - even if you fix the GPU microarchitecture - it's still the wrong numbers!
The maximum size of a block is not equal to the maximum number of threads which may be resident on an SM. It is quite typical for multiple blocks to be resident on an SM, with warps from different blocks getting scheduled by availability. CUDA has always (?) defined the maximum block size to be 1024 threads - no more and no less, regardless of the microarchitecture.
As for the maximum grid size - that's more of a "numeric limits" kind of a thing. At the same table, you will find :









Maximum x -dimension of a grid of thread blocks
231 - 1


Maximum y- or z-dimension of a grid of thread blocks
65536



These maxima don't depend on the block size in the threads, or on the maximum block size in threads. And while they depend on your microarchitecture in principle (e.g. NVIDIA could make a card which supports 128K blocks in the Y axis of the grid) - in practice, these values have not changed for many years.

Note, though, that even if the max number of resident threads is not the relevant number, if you choose a block size which doesn't _divide_ the max-resident-threads, then you will necessarily have some "slack" of potential resident threads you're not using: 1024-thread blocks with 1536 max resident threads means an SM will have either 0 or 1 resident blocks, and never utilize the potential for 512 more threads (= 16 more warps) - as @RobertCrovella mentions. But then again - whoever said you need to have those extra resident warps? Maybe your 1024 threads (= 32 warps) is enough to keep the SM busy? It's possible - depending on how your kernel code utilizes SM resources and how your warps interact.
